# Optimizing linear combination of logarithmic functions

Tags: optimization

I would like to be directed to the proper literature regarding the following problem:

Given a constant sum of $x_n$ values:

$\sum_{n=1}^{N}{\left. {x_n}\right.} = C$

where $x_n ≥ 1$

Find the maximum of the following expression:

$\sum_{n=1}^{N}{\left. {a_n} \log{\left({x_n}\right) }\right.}$

where the $a_n > 0$ values are constants, and the $x_n$ values are free to change, given that their sum will remain constant.

What is the official name or category of this optimization problem? Could someone recommend a book or a website where it is explained how to solve it?

Comment: This is a nonlinear optimization problem with bound constraints on each variable and one linear constraint.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici thank you. If I get a book about basic nonlinear optimization, that would cover this topic?

Comment: You could find zillions of them ! Cheers and have fun (as I had for 60+ years).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling $y_n = x_n - 1$ we have the equivalent problem

$$
\max \sum_{n=1}^N a_n\ln(y_n+1)\ \ \text{s. t.}\ \ \ \sum_{n=1}^N y_n  = C-N
$$

so the lagrangian reads

$$
L(y,\lambda) = \sum_{n=1}^N a_n\ln(y_n+1)-\lambda\left( \sum_{n=1}^N y_n - C + N\right)
$$

The stationary points are the solutions for

$$
\nabla L = 0 = \left\{\begin{array}{rcl}\frac{a_n}{y_n+1}&=&\lambda\\
\sum_{n=1}^N y_n &=& C-N
\end{array}\right.
$$

substituting

$$
y_n = \frac{a_n}{\lambda}-1
$$

into the restriction we have

$$
\frac{1}{\lambda}\sum_{n=1}^N a_n-N = C - N
$$

or

$$
\lambda = \frac 1C\sum_{n=1}^N a_n\Rightarrow y_n = \frac{a_n C}{\sum_{n=1}^N a_n}-1\Rightarrow x_n =  \frac{a_n C}{\sum_{n=1}^N a_n}
$$

expecting of course that $a_k, C$ are such that $\frac{a_n C}{\sum_{n=1}^N a_n}\ge 1$. Here, as $\log$ is an strict increasing function, there exist $C$ such that this positive condition is verified.

Comment: Thank you,  +1, I'll have a look at it when I get home. In the meantime I've found these videos from Khan Academy, which explained a lot: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yuqB-d5MjZA

Comment: I understood it finally. Now I tried the same method on the linear combination of polynomials of degree 3, but it gets very messy after expressing $x_n$, and trying to substitute back into the sum constraint equation (because the lambdas are under a square root). Would you have any hints?

Comment: Considering $x^3$ instead $\ln(x)$ we have $3a_nx_n^2=\lambda\to x_n = \sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{3a}}\to \lambda =3 \left(\frac{C^2}{\sum\sqrt{a_n}}\right)$

Comment: Well I tried $f_n(x_n) = b_n*x_n^3 + c_n*x_n^2 + d_n*x_n + e_n$  But I guess this is a different issue now. Now I try certain tricks, like eliminating the odd powers.